# Glitch com JPopupMenu em Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, menu, popup

Criei uma pequena aplicação para testar um JPopupMenu juntamente com um JTextField, o problema que encontrei é que quando clico muito rápido, várias vezes seguidas juntamente selecionando os itens uma vez ou outra ele da um "glitch"/bug na tela, ele deixa os componentes gráficos todo estranho. Acontece também se for fazendo isso devagar, selecionando alguns itens, ir fazendo aparecer e desaparecer o Popup. Lembrando que o problema acontece randomicamente, não tendo nem uma ação em especial para faze-lo acontecer.

**Código: (Algumas partes geradas pelo Netbeans)**

```
package blackscreendeveloper.loginteste.view;

import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Login() {

        initComponents();

        JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();

        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("Item 2");
        JMenuItem item3 = new JMenuItem("Item 3");

        menu.add(item1);
        menu.add(item2);
        menu.add(item3);

        txtLogin.setComponentPopupMenu(menu);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        txtLogin = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(txtLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 260, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addComponent(txtLogin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtLogin;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Imagem do Glitch: (Ficou dessa forma nesse caso, mas pode mudar)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Testei aqui seu código e esse problema não ocorreu de forma alguma.

Comment: O que seria então? Problema na maquina? Você testou na forma que descrevi? Clicando de forma rápida?

Comment: Sim, o problema não ocorreu.

Comment: Alguma ideia do que poderia ser?

Comment: Outra coisa incoerente na pergunta é o fato do código ter o LAF nimbus configurado mas seu print não está com o LAF nimbus.

Comment: O print postado é da forma que eu executei. O LAF pode estar sendo a causa? Qual você usou?

Comment: Não sei, como não é possivel reproduzir o bug, não tenho como sugerir nada pois não sei a origem.Mas suspeito que não tem nada a ver com java, senão o problema ocorreria comigo tambem.

Comment: Vou testar no computador de casa e irei retornar, para verificar se o problema ocorre em outro computador também.

Comment: Pode ser a ide tambem. Tenta gerar o jar e simular pra ver se ocorre. Se sim, pode ser versao do jdk com problemas, ou até o recurso do aero do seu windows(pelo print você parece estar usando windows 7)

Comment: Testei no Windows 10 agora mesmo. Poraqui está ok... estranho. Estou usando o Nimbus também no windows 10 então descartado ser o LAF. Vou testar em outro PC com Windows 7 amanhã e volto para um parecer. Agradeço até o momento.

Comment: Então você acaba de constatar que não há problema algum com o java e nem com a API swing :)

Comment: Irei testar no Windows 7 novamente amanhã para ver o problema. Mas provavelmente é realmente o PC que eu estava.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testei em outro PC com Windows 7 e em outro com Windows 10 e por minha surpresa nada ocorreu, funcionou perfeitamente. Suponho eu que possa ser algum driver, programa ou algo do tipo que está fazendo ocorrer o problema. Caso alguém tiver o mesmo problema, sugiro testar em outro computador, caso continuar ocorrendo, é válido uma possível reinstalação de drivers ou formatação do computador. Agradeço as ajudas.